# How to delete an item from a list in React?

Tags: reactjs

code that i have done, you can find it in the link below  :
https://codepen.io/   carlidev/   pen/LYRENJO

Comment: One, please post your code here if it's short. Second, show us more of the detail. Third, try using Codesandbox instead of Codepen when you what to show React code as it's more convenient for us to work on.

Comment: this is the codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-poitras-m5x2h

Comment: Sorry, but we need the code to be posted *here*. External sites have a tendency to disappear, but we want questions to be useful for future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Output:

[image]

Here is the example where if an item is present then the item is deleted, and if the item entered is not present then that new item is added to the List:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState(["Pune", "Delhi", "Three"]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!name) {
      alert("Enter the city name");
      return;
    }
    let tempList = cities.filter(
      (city) => city.toLowerCase() !== name.toLowerCase()
    );

    if (tempList.length === cities.length) {
      tempList.push(name);
      setCities(tempList);
      return;
    } else {
      setCities(tempList);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {cities.map((city) => (
        <p>{city}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-buck-f19fd?file=/src/App.js:0-888)

In Your given Example here are few changes you should make:

```js
//PostList.js

//

import React from "react";

class PostList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const newPost = this.props.posts.map((e, i) => {
      return (
        <ul key={i} className="list">
          <li>
            {e.title}
            <br />
            {e.textarea}
            <br />
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.handleDelete(e.textarea);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
            <br />
            <button>EDIT</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return <div>{newPost}</div>;
  }
}

export default PostList;
```

and

```js
// Home.js


import React from "react";
import PostList from "./PostList";
import PostForm from "./PostForm";

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      form: {
        title: "",
        textarea: ""
      }
    };
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

// modified deleteitem function, never use index as a key while rendering list.
  deleteItem(textarea) {
    console.log(textarea);
    const filteredItems = this.state.posts.filter((item) => item.textarea!== textarea);
    this.setState({
      posts: filteredItems
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        form: {
          ...prevState.form,
          [name]: event.target.value
        }
      };
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        posts: [prevState.form, ...prevState.posts],
        form: {
          title: "",
          textarea: ""
        }
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PostForm
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
          form={this.state.form}
        />
        <PostList posts={this.state.posts} handleDelete={this.deleteItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: can you check here, where is the problem : https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-poitras-m5x2h

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-gould-csvqn?file=/src/Home.js:436-611 here.

Comment: thank you! can you help me with EDIT function?

Comment: I don't have any idea how to create the "edit function".

Comment: It's pretty much the same as Delete, You search the post that you have clicked to edit, modify it according to new data and update the state with a new updated posts list. 
Please do try on your own, at least for 15-20 min, if you still can't solve it then post the question, will surely help you :)

Comment: i have tried this : https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-poitras-m5x2h?file=/src/PostList.js

Comment: we can make a if statement, after the new post will be added, we delete the current post that we changed

Comment: but, how to make that after i click the dit button, the list will be shown in the input fields?

Comment: can you send me the code?

Comment: hi, i just created the "edit function", but when i edit the input fields, the text added to list as a new one. hoe can i fix this problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-fire-2639k

Comment: amazing, you just have to implement filtering logic now. good job

Answer (score 0):

First of all: correct your url.
Second of all: filter seems fine, but what is this `item.i` property? Are you sure your objects have such property and it's not an index of an array?

Comment: https://codepen.io/carlidev/pen/LYRENJO

Comment: i have update the code, to be more clear.

Comment: i just uploaded the code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-poitras-m5x2h